# How I can detect when device receive data from server in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets

How I can detect when device receive data from server in Objective-C
I have 2 problem:

> 1. I want to connect to server to receive data through socket. What is library i can use?
> 2. I connect to server through socket and i want to detect whenever server push data to device, device listen and receive data? How i can create a thread to listen when server push data?
>      this? I am using Xcode 5.1, iOS 7.x

Updated:
I have reading and follow from here: [Connect server with socket of raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

But now I have a question: how keep alive socket during app open and how to detect when app receive data from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide which socket technology you want to use. Because you/your teammate will be implementing it on the other side. Sockets have one tiny little problem with their awesomness - they tend to be unstable thanks to unstable mobile network. Consider using **REST API + APN** (Apple Push Notifications).

In case you really really need to stick with sockets, make up your mind which kind you want to use:

- TCP/UDP Socket ([CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket))
- Socket.IO ([SocketIO - ObjC](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc))

Both of them are working great and used widely. The main difference is that Socket.IO has implemented a feature called heartbeat - you always know whether you're connected or not. With TCP socket (especially the framework mentioned above), you don't know that the server is down until you start sending/receiving data (the only way to find out is timeout). Other thing is that Socket.IO is very dynamic framework and is still evolving, yet the framework is very usable. I have implemented both many times, personally I'd go with Socket.IO, but that totally depends on what is implemented on the server side.

Your *other* question - detect when app receives data:

- **When app is on and opened** - both frameworks are made for that quite well
- **When app is in the background** - not really, you'll need [APN](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) for that. Change the strategy - receive notification from server that something should be downloaded.
- **When app is closed** - APN only...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I absolutely believe that SocketIO is great framework but i see that SocketIO is working only with Socket.IO/Node.js server and my server running with java environment. 
And CocoaAsyncSocket. I can't use it.. this message always say "time out".

Comment: Well yes, it sort of started along with Node.js, but you can also implement the server side in Python (https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) and that works like a charm too :-)

Comment: OK..i know..thanks for support..but last question, is socket live when i push to another view.
Example: in view 1: connect to socket -> push to view 2 -> server sent data to client => is view 1 can listen and receive data?

Comment: Yes, when you push, the view doesn't dealloc - only when you pop a view, then that view will dealloc. It is a good practice, though, that you make a wrapper object for your object, that handles all the communication and only provides data to the views via protocol methods. When you push a view, you pass the wrapper object's pointer in `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using the 
   [Socket.IO Objective C library.](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc)
2. The library allows you to setup delegate methods that are called when messages are received.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library as well for socket programing in IOS . [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)